# Float gets rounded when using dataframe.at, but not dataframe.iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a section of working code which sets the value of a column/index pair

```
g_observed["observed_magnitude"] = 0

i=1
print(g_observed["observed_magnitude"].iloc[i])
g_observed["observed_magnitude"].iloc[i] = 3.141

print(g_observed["observed_magnitude"].iloc[i])
print(g_observed.at[i, "observed_magnitude"])
```

Output

```
0
3.141
3.141
```

I am trying to identify where warnings about chain indexes are occurring. I suspect it is this section above, however when I change the code to set with df.at, the float values are rounded. Am I missing something obvious?

Also the chain index warning does not appear when using Jupyter notebooks - only when running from terminal. Is there a way to turn the warning on in the notebooks? Thanks

```
g_observed["observed_magnitude"] = 0

i=1
print(g_observed["observed_magnitude"].iloc[i])

g_observed.at[i, "observed_magnitude"] = 3.141

print(g_observed["observed_magnitude"].iloc[i])
print(g_observed.at[i, "observed_magnitude"])
```

Output

```
0
3
3
```